# Preview PDF files on iOS 11.2

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, uidocumentinteraction, quicklook

I ran into this bug that prevents my app from displaying PDF using `UIDocumentInteractionController` or `QLPreviewController`: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/91835

According to the suggestions, the solution is to copy files to documents or tmp folders and load files from there.

However, this does not work for me. Loading the files from `.documentDirectory` or `NSTemporaryDirectory()` produces the same error, but now not only on device, but also in simulator.

**Edit:**
The following code solved the problem for me:

```
func copyFiles(fileName: String) -> URL {
        let filemgr = FileManager.default
        filemgr.delegate = self

        let tempDocsFolder = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).path

        // my fileName is in format "file.pdf"
        let fileSplit = fileName.components(separatedBy: ".")
        let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileSplit[0], ofType: fileSplit[1])
        let destPath = "\(tempDocsFolder)/\(fileName)"

        do {
            try? filemgr.copyItem(atPath: filePath!, toPath: destPath)
        }

        return URL.init(fileURLWithPath: destPath)
    }
```

Then returned URL is then feeded to the `UIDocumentInteractionController`. The reason it didn't work for me before was because I tried to copy my files to `/tmp/documents/`, but the files must be copied to the root of the tmp folder: `/tmp/` (I have no idea why).

Answer (score 0):

Check for case-sensitivity of resources(File names).

Add any screen shots of the code.

Comment: I believe the case-sensitivity is consistent (everything is in lowercase). I added a screenshot of the code.

Comment: Can you check whether the resource file is added to target on not?

Comment: Yes, it is under Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources.

Comment: What is the iOS version of the device?

Comment: Can you share log of the fileUrl in device?

Comment: It's running on 11.2.6, which is probably the issue: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/91835 It looks like a bug on Apple's side.

Comment: Yup, i have seen the same. That link might be helpfull.